# device naming mismatch

Tags: udev, devices

I had some mess in restoring my system from a cloned image, but finally succeeded.
But booting up and launching GParted (or blkid, etc.)  I get that the device naming has slightly changed from before : the system HD has become /sdb, while /sda is now associated to a second HD. No problem since the fstab is working with the UUIDs.
However, launching a live GParted I find that the denomination is inverted: the bootable HD is /sda here.
I never encountered such a mismatch before, and would like to know how it might happened and possibly correct it to avoid confusion in taking back-ups.
Thanks for help.

*---  update  ---*

Today, I repeated the commands below and found that the HD's were swapped: /sdb = DEP, /sdc = DAT.
From an external live application, instead, they resulted swapped back.

So now my question becomes:
a) is it "normal" that the internal HD's (apart the USB ones) are given different names after reboot, while the fstab file is unchanged ?
b) is the above normal when booting from different live OS's ?

a) fdisk -l

```
 :~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD5000LPCX-2
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa1721481

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 976773119 976771072 465.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sda: 232.89 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk model: CT250MX500SSD1  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 8BD4973B-8ED8-4E4E-9697-F99AAC5C29D1

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624 157931519 156880896 74.8G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  471719936 488396799  16676864    8G Linux swap
/dev/sda4  157931520 314812415 156880896 74.8G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  314812416 471693311 156880896 74.8G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sdc: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD5000LPCX-2
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa0531363

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 976773119 976771072 465.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdd: 465.73 GiB, 500074283008 bytes, 976707584 sectors
Disk model: Elements 10B8   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf55dd744

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1        2048 976707583 976705536 465.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

b)mount

```
    mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=4014420k,nr_inodes=1003605,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=816100k,mode=755)
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=29,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=22869)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdc1 on /media/DEP type fuseblk (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/DAT type fuseblk (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=816096k,nr_inodes=204024,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

c) df

```
~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             4014420         0   4014420   0% /dev
tmpfs             816100      1452    814648   1% /run
/dev/sda5       76630796  37659824  35032568  52% /
tmpfs            4080488         0   4080488   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda1         523244      3484    519760   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sdc1      488385532 356804224 131581308  74% /media/DEP
/dev/sdb1      488385532  85393624 402991908  18% /media/DAT
tmpfs             816096       104    815992   1% /run/user/1000
```

d) blkid

```
~$ sudo blkid
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="DAT" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="607D3FC24755E8F0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="a1721481-01"
/dev/sda1: UUID="4CC3-896F" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="ec058c4e-6a6f-4092-900d-7cd848fbdb33"
/dev/sda2: UUID="257dc913-2dbb-4fa9-92b7-c44d38c26824" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="A2" PARTUUID="7790face-c85c-4c73-921c-c1af2c4f5ad4"
/dev/sda3: UUID="cc1c51cb-696e-4dd6-9e11-8c419914897a" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="5c968f4e-4102-4a80-b41d-ced206c5305b"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="a64-tst" UUID="e1c67118-0497-4652-8a08-addf8ee6dce0" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="A4" PARTUUID="c5275a00-4586-4a83-98ec-6ad2fe0d1488"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="a64be" UUID="2f875747-4d12-4bc7-bd16-15fc18f4e828" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="A5" PARTUUID="19a2c00d-0441-42c3-b550-bdc3fe91b3f9"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="DEP" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="076038063EB7EFAE" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="a0531363-01"
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="Elements" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="B4D48115D480DB4E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="f55dd744-01"
/dev/sr1: BLOCK_SIZE="2048" UUID="2022-07-05-11-24-53-00" LABEL="HonorSuiteM-bM-^@M-^@M-bM-^@M-^@M-bM-^@M-^@M-bM-^@M-^@M-bM-^@M-^@M-bM-^@M-^@" TYPE="iso9660" PTTYPE="mac"
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackexchange. Can you provide output that shows what you're seeing? Like `fdisk -l`, `mount`, and `df`?

Comment: @brunson: thanks, alright, I will do asap

Comment: What I would refer to as your "system disk" (where your root mount point lives, under `/`) is on sda. Your `/boot` partition is on sdb, which is odd. `/boot` is only used at (wait for it) boot time. It's where grub finds the files to launch the linux kernel from. I suspect it's related to booting into windows since sdb also seems to be where your NTFS filesystem is found.

Comment: Yes, my SYS (let's call so) is on /sda, it has 3 partitions with different bootable versions of Debian, +/sda1 = /boot/efi + /sda3=swap. The other HD's (DAT,DEP, Elements) contains just data and shall not be bootable, no Windows. But actually, in the restoring I cloned the /sda image on /sdb, but later I should have succeeded in putting all back. Now (by gparted) I do not see any /boot partition other than in /sda=SYS.